# Align image in html5

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<header>
    <div id="title">                
        <img alt="logo" src="/Content/logo.gif" />
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Auctions</li>
            <li>Segmentation</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

That generate this:

[image: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4290/38501640.png]

I want that the image will be above the white box(that it will align according to the image). How do I do it?

BTW I use the default asp.net mvc3 template.

Thanks.

Comment: Above or on top of? Can you post your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're floating these elements. If so, try setting the overflow property of the header:

```
header {
   overflow: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to place 100px above it's natural positon, use this.

```
#title img {
   margin-top: 100px
}
```

or this:

```
#title img {
   position: relative;
   top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing this in Internet Explorer < 9, make sure you're defining the tag `<header>` using

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.createElement('header')</script>
```

or a [library](http://modernizr.com/) and styling it as a block-level element (`header{display:block}`) before trying to style it.